# Problem when trying to make request with proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Here is my code:

```
headers = {
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
            "referer": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{}/inventory".format(options['steamid'])
        }
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/{}/{}/{}?l={}&count={}&start_assetid={}'.format(options['steamid'], options['appid'], options['contextid'], options['language'], options['count'], last_assetid)

proxy = self.proxy()
proxies = {
          'http': proxy,
          'https': proxy
}
req = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
```

Proxies (when printed):
{'http': 'https://91.188.243.130:9049:xxx:xxx', 'https': 'https://91.188.243.130:9049:xxx:xxx'}

Error which I get:
Failed to parse: 91.188.241.137:9049:xxx:xxx

Comment: What is xxx:xxx supposed to be?

Comment: @SimonF proxy pass and login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) username and password is passed to a proxy like this

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'}
```